# On the sample path right continuity and hitting times

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have a question on the sample path right-continuity of a stochastic process.

Let $X=\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a stochastic process on a locally compact separable metric space $E$. We assume that $X$ starts from $x \in E$ and the sample path of $X$ is right continuous on $[0,\infty)$ with left limits in $E$.

Let $A $ be an open subset of $E$. We set
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{A}=\inf\{t>0 \mid X_t \in A\}.
\end{align*}
We consider the following event. For $t>0$,
\begin{align*}
\{X_{kt/2^n}\in E \setminus A \mid k=1,2,\ldots,2^n,\,\,n=1,2,\ldots\}
\end{align*}

it clearly holds that $X_t \in E \setminus A$.
This, I think the above event is equal to $\{t<\sigma_A\}$. Is this wrong?